# AjAX can't call the MQTT of php

Tags: php, ajax, mqtt

I have a program using ajax. The program will post the data(the field of text) to abc.php via ajax.
Then the abc.php will publish the data(the field of text) to MQTT(Mosquitto) server. But it didn't work and got the message " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

I am sure that the individule php for mqtt can work before going with ajax.

How can I fix this? Thank you for your help.

**ajax() call:**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'abc.php',
    data: {text: '1234'},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});

</script>
```

**php code (abc.php):**

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$client = new Mosquitto\Client;
$client->setCredentials('','');
$client->onConnect(function() use (client){
 $client->publish('abc/command','{"item" :$text}', 1);
 $client->disconnect();
 });
$client->connect('mqtthost',1883);
$client->loopForever();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're sending `{"item" :$text}` to MQTT not `{"item" :1234}`. The first one is not valid JSON.
You have to use double quotes if you want to interpolate a string into another string.
It should be `"{\"item\" :$text}"`, unless $text is not numeric then it should have the escaped double quotes as well.

Also, try to avoid making JSON by hand you can use json_encode to produce your data.

```
$text = (int)$_POST['text'];
$client = new Mosquitto\Client;
$client->setCredentials('','');
$client->onConnect(function() use (client){
  $client->publish('abc/command',json_encode(["item" => $text]), 1);
  $client->disconnect();
});
$client->connect('mqtthost',1883);
$client->loopForever();
```